# How to get updated state immediately with redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

After user submits a form I dispatched the create course function.

```
const handleCreateCourse = () => {
    dispatch(createCourse(courseData));
    // ??
};
```

How can I get and use the "_id" of newly created course immediately which will come from backend and will be saved in the updated state? So that I can do the following:

```
const courses = useSelector(state => state.courses);

const handleCreateCourse = () => {
    dispatch(createCourse(courseData));
    // ??
    const newCourse = courses[courses.length-1];
    history.push(`/course/${newCourse._id}`);
};
```

The createCourse function is using redux-thunk and looks like this:

```
export const createCourse = (course) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.createCourse(course);
        dispatch({ type: CREATE_COURSE, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return API responses in thunk after dispatching the action.

E.g.

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
const thunk = ReduxThunk.default;

const api = {
  async createCourse(name) {
    return { data: { _id: '100', name } };
  },
};

function coursesReducer(state = [], action) {
  return state;
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  courses: coursesReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

const CREATE_COURSE = 'CREATE_COURSE';
export const createCourse = (course) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.createCourse(course);
    dispatch({ type: CREATE_COURSE, payload: data });
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const handleCreateCourse = () => {
  store.dispatch(createCourse({ name: 'math' })).then((newCourse) => {
    console.log('newCourse: ', newCourse);
    console.log(`/course/${newCourse._id}`);
  });
};

handleCreateCourse();
```

The exeuction result:

```
newCourse:  { _id: '100', name: { name: 'math' } }
/course/100
```